# Selecting more than one column from deeply nested mySQL queries

Tags: mysql

```
select 
    a 
from 
    table_1 
where 
    b in ( 
       select 
           c 
       from 
           table_c 
       where 
           d in ( 
              select 
                 e 
              from 
                 table_e 
           )
      );
```

I want to pass 'd' also in the final result....any way?

Comment: how your tables looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN`:

```
select 
    a ,
    d
from 
    table_1 
inner join table_c
    ON b = c
inner join table_e
    ON d = e
```

Comment: One more question Stephan, I actually have to select only rows for a particular value of a column in table_e in the above question. Something like this:  select a from table_1 where b in ( select c from table_c where d in ( select e from table_e where table_e.column='123');   So, using your answer, your modified answer would be : select 
    a ,
    d
from 
    table_1 
inner join table_c
    ON b = c
inner join table_e
    ON d = e where table_e.column='123'; or do i need to place where clause somewhere else?

Comment: @Abhay: it should work like you did or you can put the condition on join like `ON d = e AND table_e.column='123'`